# angularjs Nested Ng-Repeat problem with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat within ng-repeat as follow

```
  <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="track in machine.noteMatrix2">
            <td>--</td>
            <td ng-repeat="step in track">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="track[$index].value"> 
   {{step.value}}</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
```

also below is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/rskLy/11/

the issue is that when i update track[$index].value for single record in machine.noteMatrix2 it gets update in all the nodes within machine.noteMatrix2

is there any solution for this??

**EDIT**

```
data

    machine.noteMatrix = [
        [false, false, false],
        [false, true, false],
        [false, false, false]
    ];
```

Comment: Provide `noteMatrix2` data and also other useful information in question. Not just in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee updated see data

Comment: Does this problem still exist?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `track[$index].value` you must use `step` and also track both **ngRepeat** by `$index`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.noteMatrix = [
    [false, false, false],
    [false, true, false],
    [false, false, false]
  ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{noteMatrix}}
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="track in noteMatrix track by $index">
        <td>-{{$index}}-</td>
        {{track}}
        <td ng-repeat="step in track track by $index">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="step"> {{step}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```